# Is there a way to transform an image using roll, pitch, and yaw?

Tags: image, rotation, transform

[image]
original image

[image]
inference roll, pitch, and yaw

[image]
rotate image from roll, pitch, yaw

The image was converted so that the person could see the front.

but the angle does not become 0.

class ImageTransformer(object):
""" Perspective transformation class for image
with shape (height, width, #channels) """

```
def __init__(self, image):
    self.image = image
    self.height = self.image.shape[0]
    self.width = self.image.shape[1]
    self.num_channels = self.image.shape[2]

def degree_to_radius(self, degree):
    return degree * math.pi / 180.0

def get_radius(self, theta, phi, gamma):
    rad_theta = self.degree_to_radius(theta)
    rad_phi = self.degree_to_radius(phi)
    rad_gamma = self.degree_to_radius(gamma)

    return rad_theta, rad_phi, rad_gamma

""" Wrapper of Rotating a Image """
def rotate_along_axis(self, theta=0, phi=0, gamma=0, dx=0, dy=0, dz=0):
    # Get radius of rotation along 3 axes
    rad_theta, rad_phi, rad_gamma = self.get_radius(theta, phi, gamma)
    
    # Get ideal focal length on z axis
    # NOTE: Change this section to other axis if needed
    dist = np.sqrt(self.height**2 + self.width**2)
    self.focal = dist / (2 * np.sin(rad_gamma) if np.sin(rad_gamma) != 0 else 1)
    dz = self.focal

    # Get projection matrix
    mat = self.get_perspective_projection_matrix(rad_theta, rad_phi, rad_gamma, dx, dy, dz)
    imat = np.linalg.inv(mat)  
    return cv2.warpPerspective(self.image.copy(), imat, (self.width, self.height))

""" Get Perspective Projection Matrix """
def get_perspective_projection_matrix(self, theta, phi, gamma, dx, dy, dz):
    
    w = self.width
    h = self.height
    f = self.focal

    # Projection 2D -> 3D matrix
    A1 = np.array([ [1, 0, -w/2],
                    [0, 1, -h/2],
                    [0, 0, 1],
                    [0, 0, 1]])
    
    # Rotation matrices around the X, Y, and Z axis
    RX = np.array([ [1, 0, 0, 0],
                    [0, np.cos(theta), -np.sin(theta), 0],
                    [0, np.sin(theta), np.cos(theta), 0],
                    [0, 0, 0, 1]])
    
    RY = np.array([ [np.cos(phi), 0, -np.sin(phi), 0],
                    [0, 1, 0, 0],
                    [np.sin(phi), 0, np.cos(phi), 0],
                    [0, 0, 0, 1]])
    
    RZ = np.array([ [np.cos(gamma), -np.sin(gamma), 0, 0],
                    [np.sin(gamma), np.cos(gamma), 0, 0],
                    [0, 0, 1, 0],
                    [0, 0, 0, 1]])

    # Composed rotation matrix with (RX, RY, RZ)
    R = np.dot(np.dot(RX, RY), RZ)
    # R = np.dot(np.dot(np.linalg.inv(RX), np.linalg.inv(RY)), np.linalg.inv(RZ))

    # Translation matrix
    T = np.array([  [1, 0, 0, dx],
                    [0, 1, 0, dy],
                    [0, 0, 1, dz],
                    [0, 0, 0, 1]])

    # Projection 3D -> 2D matrix
    A2 = np.array([ [f, 0, w/2, 0],
                    [0, f, h/2, 0],
                    [0, 0, 1, 0]])

    # Final transformation matrix
    return np.dot(A2, np.dot(T, np.dot(R, A1)))
```

The matrix mat calculated using roll, pitch, and yaw was converted using an inverse matrix.

I'd like some advice for rotating the image in terms of roll, pitch, and yaw.